# make: *** No rule to make target 'php', needed by 'test-newsletter-only'. Stop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile (being read by GNU Make 4.1) containing the following line:

`test-newsletter-only: php bin/phpunit src/AppBundle/Tests/Service/NewsletterFromPageServiceTest.php`

... and when I run `make test-newsletter-only` in my shell, I get the following:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'php', needed by
>   'test-newsletter-only'.  Stop.

I have verfified with `php -v` that a valid copy of PHP is installed in the environment where I'm running this. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look through make docs.
You can find rule syntax [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html)

php is interpreted as a prerequisite, while I assume you intended it to be part of the recipe. Take it to the new line.